# Angular 2 : jasmin test case for activateRoute.snapshot.queryParams[""]

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am reading some values from url by using ActiveRoute.

```
http://localhost:4200/project-test/#/add?orderId=156&customerNumber=431
```

I have separate component to read the values in ngOnInit() method.

snippet :

```
...

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
          public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
          private customerAPIService : CustomerAPIService) {}

ngOnInit() {

   this.orderId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams["orderId"];
   ...
}
```

Test case :

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CreateCustomer } from './create-customer.component';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerAPIService } from "app/repackaging/service/customer.api.service";

describe('CreateCustomer', () => {
  let component;

  let mockActiveRoute;
  let mockCustomerAPIService;
  let mockQueryParamMap;

  beforeEach(() => {

     mockQueryParamMap = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockQueryParamMap', ['queryParams']);
     mockActiveRoute = {queryParamMap: mockQueryParamMap};

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers : [
           {
              provide: ActivatedRoute,
              useFactory: () => mockActiveRoute
           },
           {
              provide: CustomerAPIService,
              userFactory: () => mockCustomerAPIService
           }
      ],
      declarations :[
          CreateCustomer
      ]
    });

        component = TestBed.createComponent(CreateCustomer).componentInstance;
    });

    it('should run ngOninit function', function () {
       component.ngOnInit();

       ...

    });
});
```

I am getting below error while writing a test

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams') in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js (line 350)**

Comment: `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams` how do you expect to access this when your `mockActivatedRoute` does not have the `snapshot` property. The `mockActivatedRoute` is what is being injected as the `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: @peeskillet agreed. do we need to create separate spy for snapshot? how can I add snapshot for mocking?

Comment: Why `queryParamMap`? You need a `snapshot` property, which in turn has its own `queryParams` property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

extending @peeskillet answer.

There was silly mistake like I was mocking queryParamMap instead of snapshot.queryparams.

```
http://localhost:4200/project-test/#/add?order=156&customerNumber=431
```

Below is the solution to mock activeroutes.snapshot.queryparams["order"].

```
 let orderId; 
 let customerNumber;

 let mockActiveRoute;
 ...

 beforeEach(() => {
    ...

    mockActiveRoute = {
      snapshot: {
        queryParams: {
          order: orderId,
          customerNumber: customerNumber
        }
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: How can i change the 'mockActiveRoute' content for another test case, for checking a different orderId?

Comment: `let route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)` then you can update the return value. `route` will be the singleton inside the dependency injection container.